# Edit a text file line by line in bash

Tags: string, bash, replace

I have a `requirements.txt` file that has the following lines-

```
PyMySQL==0.9.3
botocore==1.12.196
boto3==1.9.188
```

I need to edit this file in-place using bash to remove all lines containing `boto3` and `botocore`. So far, I've come up with-

```
while read a ; do echo ${a//boto3==1.9.188/} ; done < requirements.txt > requirements.txt.t ; mv requirements.txt{.t,}
```

.. which successfully removes the line containing `boto3==1.9.188`. However, this version number could be anything, say `1.10.122`.

How do I generalize the script above to remove all lines containing `boto3` and `botocore` strings? Or is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -vE '^(botocore|boto3)\W' requirements.txt > requirements.txt.new && \
    mv requirements.txt.new requirements.txt
```

Explanation:

- `-v` tells grep to output lines that *don't* match the pattern, and skip lines that *do* match.
- `-E` tells grep to allow extended regular expressions, which we use for alternation.
- `^` anchors the pattern to the beginning of the line so that it won't match `foobotocore==1.2.3`.
- The `(x|y)` construct matches either `x` or `y`.  (To add a third package, just add another `|` to create `(x|y|z)`.)
- `\W` in the pattern matches a "non-word character" so that the pattern won't match `botocorefoo==1.2.3`.
- `&&` only invokes the `mv` command if `grep` was successful and matched at least one line (prevent clobbering the whole file).

Answer (score 2):

Use `awk`

```
awk '!/(botocore|boto3)/' requirements.txt > requirements.txt.t && mv requirements.txt.t requirements.txt
```

Comment: concise answer. Although, it also removes the line with `botocorefoo==1.10.122`. How to address this?

Comment: In that case write botocore=|boto3=

Comment: A python requirements file doesn't have more than two = in a line

Answer (score 1):

Use `ed`:

```
printf 'g/botocore/d\ng/boto3/d\nwq\n' | ed requirements.txt
```

`ed` works by reading a set of commands (terminated by newlines) from standard input and applying them to the file named by its argument. The commands should look familiar if you are familiar with `sed` (indeed, `sed` is a **s**tream **ed**itor based on `ed`).

- `g/botocore/d` selects each line matching the regular expression `botocore` and applies the `d` (delete) command to each.
- `g/boto3/d` does the same for lines matching `boto3`.
- `wq` saves the changes and quotes.

Comment: looks neat. Could you add some description of what's happening here? Also, your answer removes the line with `botocorefoo==1.12.222` which shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Use perl:

I like perl in this case because

1. You don't need to worry about file manipulation
2. You can easily make a backup of the file as well.

Command:

```
$ perl -ni -e '/\b(boto3|botocore)\b/ || print;' requirements.txt
```

Breakdown of options

- -n iterate over lines in the file
- -i edit the file in place.
- -i.orig edit the file in place and make a backup with the extension '.orig'
- -e execute the perl command

/\b(boto3|botocore)\b/ || print;

This reads if the line doesn't match a word with boto3 or botocore then print.  The \b indicates a word boundary.

Example:

```
$ cat requirements.txt
PyMySQL==0.9.3
botocore==1.12.196
boto3==1.9.188
$ perl -ni -e '/\b(boto3|botocore)\b/ || print;' requirements.txt
$ cat requirements.txt
PyMySQL==0.9.3
$
```

Example with making backup of file called "requirements.txt.orig"

```
$ cat requirements.txt
PyMySQL==0.9.3
botocore==1.12.196
boto3==1.9.188
$ perl -ni.orig -e '/\b(boto3|botocore)\b/ || print;' requirements.txt
$ cat requirements.txt
PyMySQL==0.9.3
$ cat requirements.txt.orig
PyMySQL==0.9.3
botocore==1.12.196
boto3==1.9.188
```